# Get JQuery value from other function

Tags: jquery

I'm really new to JQuery. And I have following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pics').bind('change', function() {
        filesize = this.files[0].size; //Value of this one
        alert(filesize);
    });

    $('#Frm001').ajaxForm(function() {
        $('span.save-notice').text('Save Changed Successfully'+filesize); //to this one
            $('span.save-notice').show(); 
        }); 
});
```

How do I actually get the value filesize from above function to ajaxFormFunction because I got error on the filesize...?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen if the ajaxForm appears before the `change` event is completed?

Comment: You should put ajaxForm in your change function.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do is this: Execute ajaxForm on change.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pics').bind('change', function() {
        filesize = this.files[0].size; //Value of this one
        alert(filesize);

        $('#Frm001').ajaxForm(function() {
           $('span.save-notice').text('Save Changed Successfully'+filesize); //to this one
              $('span.save-notice').show(); 
        });
    }); 
});
```